# How to send date to a javascript date with flutter?

Tags: flutter, express

I'm trying to send the date from flutter to a express backend, and it isn't send with the proper format. What is the best way to send the date to the server?

Comment: The best way is to find the date format that the express backend server expects, and then format your date to that format.

Answer (score 2):

When sending dates from Flutter to an Express backend, you need to ensure that the date is formatted properly so that it can be parsed correctly on the server side. There are a few options for sending dates to the server:

**ISO 8601 Format:** This is a widely recognized and recommended format for representing dates and times. It looks like this: "2023-07-17T12:34:56Z". In Flutter, you can use the toIso8601String() method on a DateTime object to convert it to this format before sending it to the server.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = dateTime.toIso8601String();
// Now send formattedDate to the server
```

Epoch Time (Unix Timestamp): This is the number of seconds (or milliseconds) that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (known as the Unix epoch). In Flutter, you can use the millisecondsSinceEpoch property of a DateTime object to get the epoch time before sending it to the server.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
int epochTime = dateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
// Now send epochTime to the server
```

**Custom String Format:** If you prefer a custom date format, you can define one and use it consistently between the Flutter app and the Express backend. However, it's generally recommended to stick to standardized formats like ISO 8601 for better interoperability and less chance of errors.
On the Express backend, you'll need to parse the date sent from the Flutter app accordingly. For example, if you're using ISO 8601 format, you can use a library like date-fns or moment.js in your Express app to parse the incoming date string.

Here's an example of parsing an ISO 8601 date using date-fns in Express:

```
const { parseISO } = require('date-fns');

app.post('/api/someEndpoint', (req, res) => {
  const { dateString } = req.body;
  const dateObject = parseISO(dateString);
  // Now you have a JavaScript Date object to work with
});
```

Remember to adjust the code based on your specific use case and the package you choose to work with on the server side.

In summary, using a standardized date format like ISO 8601 or Epoch Time and ensuring proper parsing on the server side will help you avoid date format issues when sending dates from Flutter to your Express backend.